# How can I make Jenkins perform a shell command after Editable Email?

Tags: git, email, jenkins, notifications

I have a situation where I need to switch WiFi networks to perform a build. Only one SSID has external connectivity, the other is where the git repository exists. I need to switch the network after the status emails have been sent but the Editable Email is ALWAYS running after the Post Build steps.

I've experimented with various plugins with no success.  Does someone have the definitive answer on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create "child" build at the same node after main build is finished.